# How to access Dynamically Generated Controls not knowing their names

Tags: asp.net

My page generates a list of check boxes at run time.  I set the Id of each of these boxes manually by assigning to each the string.Format("checkbox_{0}, n} where n is a running number.

How to I find out the list of checkbox controls from codebehind?  I couldn't find them in Page.Form.Controls.  Where are they placed?

(I can see the checked checkboxes in Request.Form but that contains client side names of each control.)

Thanks.

-

---More info----

My iterative loop Adds CheckBoxes to a Panel control (created in the mark-up page) as follows:

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
checkbox.Text = "Add to list";
checkbox.ID = string.Format("checkbox_{0}", n.ToString("0"));
Panel1.Controls.Add(checkbox);
```

The checkboxes show up nicely on the page.  I can tick.  When I submit the Http POST stream contains all those ticked ones.

On post back, Panel1.Controls.Count is 0.  When the page was first generated, Panel1.Controls.Count was 200, as it contained lots of LieteralControls for layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the findcontrol method on page object or parent control object to find that checkbox object. like:

```
CheckBox chx=(CheckBox)Page.FindControl("Checkbox1");
if(chx!=null)
chx.Checked = false;
```

you can put this insode the loop also like:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
CheckBox chx=(CheckBox)Page.FindControl("Checkbox"+n);
if(chx!=null)
chx.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I cannot find them in Page.FindControl or Page.Form.FindControl.  Any Page settings I must set for this to work?

Comment: can you show the code where you are dynamically adding the checkboxes on page. in which Parent control are you adding the checkboxes?

Comment: I have added more info in my original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> On post back, Panel1.Controls.Count is 0. When the page was first generated, Panel1.Controls.Count was 200, as it contained lots of LieteralControls for layout.

If you add controls dynamically in this way, you need to add them again (same ids, same order) on each postback.

Which means you need to persist whatever info you need to add them again.  For example, you could store the number of checkboxes in ViewState, then regenerate that number of checkboxes on each post back.

Comment: Thanks.  But what I really want is to read the status of the CheckBoxes and proceed with processing them.  Right now I can't see them.  Aren't the dynamically created CheckBoxes posted back in the ViewState?  Shouldn't ASP.NET then combine with the Http POST data to determine the state of each CheckBox?

Comment: Found this: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx  Sounds like it not so straightforward to read values of dynamically created controls.

Comment: @OldGeezer - the main constraint is that you need to recreate the control tree after each postback.  I don't think the article's completely accurate - I believe you can add dynamic controls after the Init phase.

Comment: From the way I understand it, dynamic controls are not in ViewState and that's why they have to be created manually.  Then the values submitted by the user have to be populated onto the recreated controls.  My question then is from where are the values taken?  In ViewState, or from Request.Forms?

Comment: @OldGeezer The values submitted by the user are populated from Request.Forms`.  ViewState holds changes made to the properties of the control on the server.  This is the same for static and dynamic controls.